# イラストレーターでSVGに書き出したベジェ曲線を、HTML内で使える形式に変換したい

Tags: html, svg

お世話になります。

HTMLの`<svg>`要素の中の`<path>`と、イラレで書き出したSVGファイルに含まれる`<path>‌`​では、ベジェ曲線の書き方が若干‌​違うようで、それを書き換える必要があるよ‌​うです。

イラストレーターで描き、SVGに書き出したベジェ曲線を、HTML中のSVGで使えるpath要素に簡単に変換できるツールなどありませんか？
または、変換の仕方の情報でも良いです。

Comment: イラレで書きだしたSVGを開いた時に書かれているコードをhtmlの<path>要素に書き換えるということです。

Comment: おっしゃるとおりhtmlの<svg>要素の中の<path>要素です！イラレで書き出したsvgファイルを開くと<path>というタグができていて、そこにペジェ曲線の情報が書いてあるのですが、htmlで書くpath要素のペジェ曲線の書き方と若干違うようで、それを書き換える必要があるようなのです。なので、手動で書き換える代わりとなる何か簡単な方法はないか思って調べております。

Comment: 同じはずですが、「若干違う」点を提示してください。

Comment: htmlにコピペしても描画されません。

Comment: 最低限の例で結構ですので、コピペして表示されない SVG の例を追加していただくと良いと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> htmlにコピペしても描画されません。

HTMLは`http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`、SVGは`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`と[XML名前空間](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#namespaces)が異なります。XMLに対応したエディタであればコピー＆ペーストを行ってもXML名前空間を適切に修正しますが、未対応のテキストエディタの場合、文字列そのままをペーストしてしまうため、誤った名前空間に展開され、その結果、正しいSVGと認識されません。

使用するツールを変更するか、[名前空間の速修講座](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)などを参考に修正する必要があります。

Comment: SVGをAtomで開いてまるまるhtmlにコピペしたら表示されました！svgのところを抜き出していたのが悪かったみたいです！ありがとうございました！