# jsで挿入したhtmlの<polygon>要素が表示されない

Tags: html, jquery, svg

htmlにあらかじめ書かれている、要素は表示されるのに、
jsで追加した要素は表示されません。
ブラウザのデベロッパーツール上では同じような表記になっているようなのですが。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[HTML]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practice</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <polygon points="50,50 150,50 150,150" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="lightgreen"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[js]

```
$(function() {
        var svg = $('svg')
            var pol = $('<polygon points="50,50 150,50 150,150" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="lightgreen">');
            svg.prepend(pol)
        });
```

Comment: この[サイト](http://defghi1977.html.xdomain.jp/tech/svgMemo/svgMemo_15.htm) が参考になると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQueryオブジェクトを生成するAPIのひとつである[jQuery(html [, ...] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)は、テキストを*raw HTML*として扱う仕様です。

> #### jQuery( html [, ...] ) Returns: jQuery
>
> Description: Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of **raw HTML**.
>
> - html  
>     Type: htmlString  
>     A string of HTML to create on the fly. **Note that this parses HTML, not XML.**

具体的には、次のような結果を生じます。

```
const jqEl = $('<polygon>');
const domEl = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon');

// jQueryはHTMLと解釈
console.assert(jqEl[0].namespaceURI === 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');

// 本来ならば次が期待される
console.assert(domEl.namespaceURI === 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
```

XML名前空間についてご存じなければ、[名前空間の速修講座](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)などを参照してご確認ください。

以下、参考のためにDOMによる操作を例示します。どうしてもjQueryを用いる場合は独自の拡張が必要かとおもわれます。その場合は別途質問していただきたいですが、あまり効果的でないのでおすすめはしません。

```js
const $svg = document.querySelector('#target');

const $el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon');
$el.setAttributeNS(null, 'points', '50,50 150,50 150,150, 50,150 125,75 150,150');
$el.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'black');
$el.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'lightgreen');
$svg.appendChild($el);
```

```html
<svg id="target" viewBox="0 0 200 200"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

[イラストレーターでSVGに書き出したベジェ曲線を、HTML内で使える形式に変換したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/36462/4236)と全く同じです。`<svg>`ではHTML名前空間に作られたタグに過ぎず、SVG画像であるとは認識されません。

[名前空間の速修講座](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)などを参考に修正する必要があります。jQueryを使用するのであれば、対応する記述が必要です。